# What is the valid range for numbers in CSS

Tags: css

I have searched the internet and it seems very hard to find this info.

When I do

```css
  div {
    width: calc(1e-10 * 1e12px);
  }
```

It sets the width to `100px`. But when I do

```css
  div {
    width: calc(1e-1000 * 1e1002px);
  }
```

It fails. Clearly, `1e1002` is out of range.

What is the valid range of numbers in CSS? Does it depend on the unit? Is it browser specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to each browser to pick limits for CSS real numbers. The spec supports a theoretically infinite range but relies on vendors to provide 'reasonable' support.

> #### 4.1. Range Restrictions and Range Definition Notation
>
> Properties can restrict numeric values to some range. If the value is outside the allowed range, then unless otherwise specified, the declaration is invalid and must be ignored.
>
> [...]
>
> CSS theoretically supports infinite precision and infinite ranges for all value types; however in reality implementations have finite capacity. UAs should support reasonably useful ranges and precisions. Range extremes that are ideally unlimited are indicated using ∞ or −∞ as appropriate.

Soruce: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#numeric-ranges

See also:

> #### 4.3. Real Numbers: the `<number>` type
>
> Number values are denoted by `<number>`, and represent real numbers, possibly with a fractional component.
>
> When written literally, a number is either an integer, or zero or more decimal digits followed by a dot (.) followed by one or more decimal digits and optionally an exponent composed of "e" or "E" and an integer. It corresponds to the `<number-token>` production in the CSS Syntax Module [CSS3SYN]. As with integers, the first character of a number may be immediately preceded by - or + to indicate the number’s sign.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#numbers